# Awk and() operator

Tags: perl, awk

I have a code in awk like this:

```
val = and($1, 0x03FFFFFF) + $2
```

I wrote the Perl version like this:

```
$val = ($1 && 0x03FFFFFF) + $2;
```

Are this lines the same?

Comment: perl comes with a2p which turns awk into Perl code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite - you want a `&`, not `&&`:

```
$val = ($1 & 0x03FFFFFF) + $2;
```

Please note that you are correct in that the [parenthesis are needed due to precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)

---

In more detail:

- Your *awk* expression uses `and()` which is defined in [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html)'s ch. "**8.1.6 Bit-Manipulation Functions of gawk**" thusly:

  > and(v1, v2) =======    Returns the bitwise AND of the values provided by v1 and v2.
- Therefore, in Perl you want a **bitwise "and"** ; not a logical one, which according to [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And) is a single ampersand: "`&`"